# Test for interface failing on WCF host

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I have the following simple interface:

```
public interface IInitialisableWcfService
{
    void Initialise();
}
```

Which I'm placing on a class that's being used as a WCF service like so:

```
public class LocalResourceManager : ILocalResourceManager, IInitialisableWcfService
```

ILocalResourceManager is the interface that's being used to set the binding configuration for the wcf endpoint.

Inside another class that we used for hosting WCF services on the fly, I have the following code that tests for the IInitialisableWcfService interface:

```
   private void Create(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceHost host = null;
            if (serviceType == typeof(IInitialisableWcfService))
            {
                // create object to initialize.
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else
            }

        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //log error
        }
    }
```

But this fails to match the LocalResourceManager manager service when it's passed in, or indeed any other service that implements IInitialisableWcfService. I've also tried this

```
  if(serviceType is IInitialisableWcfService)
```

But that doesn't work either.

I'm not sure what the issue is here. Three possibilities:

1) The syntax for checking and interface is wrong. I find this unlikely.

2) Because the WCF endpoint is registered with an ILocalResourceManager interface, the object is not exposing its IInitialisableWcfService over WCF

3) Passing around a Type rather than an actual class means you can't check for interfaces

Or possibly none of the above. Assistance greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in `Create()` and inspect the value of `serviceType`? I think it's going to be `ILocalResourceManager`, which has no relation whatsoever to `IInitialisableWcfService`.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I'm not sure what value I'm looking to inspect to find what Interface is available at that point. I can set the breakpoint and inspect the serviceType object but it has a lot of properties, none of which seems entirely useful. "DeclaringType" is null.

Comment: Just want to know what the `FullName` property is. Most likely you're only seeing the interface that is actually being exposed as a service.

Comment: serviceType.FullName "Employer.Namespace.ResourceManager.Local.LocalResourceManager" string ... not an interface, obviously

Comment: Ah, so you're getting the concrete implementing type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Type` of `serviceType` is the actual concrete type that's implementing the service, so you just need to check if the service type is assignable to the interface you want:

```
if (typeof(IInitialisableWcfService).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType))
{
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had no idea you could check for interfaces in that fashion.